# AS3 Flash How to make text fields required?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to know how to put restrictions in the fields like if the user didn't type anything or still has a blank field, then it should not submit but shows *required field or something like that. Examples would be great.

The codes. I don't know where to start from here

```
var fllname:TextField;
var address:TextField;
var ContactNo:TextField;
var quantity:TextField;
var otrack:TextField;


btnSubmit1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, submit);

function submit(e:MouseEvent):void{
var urlvars: URLVariables = new URLVariables;

urlvars.fllname = fllname.text;
urlvars.Oadd = address.text;
urlvars.ContactNo = ContactNo.text;
urlvars.oquantiy = quantity.text;
urlvars.otrack = otrack.text;
urlvars.cake = txtCake.text;
urlvars.frosting = txtFrosting.text;
urlvars.topping = txtToppings.text;
urlvars.topping2 = txtToppings2.text;
urlvars.filling = txtFilling.text;
urlvars.amt = lblAmount.text;

var urlreq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/MCC/order.php");
urlreq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
urlreq.data = urlvars;

var loader : URLLoader = new URLLoader;
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

loader.load(urlreq);
nextFrame();

}
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @CyanAngel edited ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `enabled` parameter to control if your `btnSubmit1` is clickable, so you will probably need to start with is disabled.

```
btnSubmit1.enabled = false;
btnSubmit1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, submit);
```

Next you will need to listen to the `TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT` event on all your TextFields

```
fllname.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT,paramChanged);
address.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT,paramChanged);
//etc etc
```

This will notify you any-time the user changes their value, you can then create a single function (or a function for each control) to test the values, once they pass you can re-enable the submit button.

```
    function paramChanged(event:TextEvent):void
    {
        if (fllname.text != "" && address.text != "")//add your other fields here
        {
            btnSubmit1.enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            btnSubmit1.enabled = false;//If something changes that means we now fail the test you will want to disable the button again
        }
    }
```

You could make custom test functions for each field as needed.